# What is Hogwarts' front gate policy?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

Are the front gates of Hogwarts typically open? Apart from students passing through at the start of term, the entrance is almost never mentioned. In Half Blood Prince, Fred and George (who are no longer students) come to visit Ron in the hospital wing, but it isn't stated who let them in. I don't recall any mention of Filch or Hagrid being responsible for opening them. In Deathly Hallows, Voldemort waits to gain entry, which was arranged ahead of time with Snape, who must come down from the school to open the gates himself.

Has Rowling ever mentioned a spell or some other requirement for gaining entry through the front gates of Hogwarts?

Comment: In Fantast Beasts: The Crimes of Grindlewald, Aurors are seen to be arriving at the middle of the bridge which leads to the main entrance.

Comment: Speak, friend and enter

Comment: but in what language do you say "friend" @Valorum?? Mermish? Gobbledegook, Troll?

Comment: @NKCampbell - Elvish, obvs. You'll also need some spare socks

Comment: @Valorum Isn't it "Speak friend and enter"?

Comment: [mellon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XjVuyYoIRwU)

Answer (score 16):

## None that we know of - until the Half Blood Prince

As far as the books go, JK Rowling never wrote anything about the security of the front gate specifically. Only explanations we got of the security on Hogwarts prior to the rise of Voldemort was in the Goblet of Fire.

> “But Hogwarts is hidden,” said Hermione, in surprise. “Everyone knows that . . . well, everyone who’s read *Hogwarts, A History*, anyway.”
>
> “Just you, then,” said Ron. “So go on — how d’you hide a place
>   like Hogwarts?”
>
> “It’s bewitched,” said Hermione. “If a Muggle looks at it, all they
>   see is a moldering old ruin with a sign over the entrance saying
>   danger, do not enter, unsafe.”
>
> *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*

These enchantments, of course, refer to protection given to the entire castle, not just the front gates. The first time enchantments on the front gate are mentioned is during the Half Blood Prince.

> But when he put out a hand to push open the gates, he found them chained shut.
>
> “*Alohomora!*” he said confidently, pointing his wand at the padlock, but nothing happened.
>
> “That won’t work on these,” said Tonks. “**Dumbledore bewitched them himself.**”
>
> *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*

The fact that Dumbledore bewitched them himself seems to imply, in context of the situation in the book, that bewitching the front gates was added security in response to the public announcement of the rise of Lord Voldemort.

This, along with the lack of information provided on the front gates in the past 5 books, would imply that there was either negligible to no security on the front gates before this.

Remember that before the rise of Voldemort, the primary security concern for Hogwarts was keeping its presence hidden from Muggles; the standard enchantments placed upon Hogwarts were probably deemed sufficient for that purpose for all parts of the grounds, including the front gates.

Answer (score 9):

In *Half-Blood Prince* we find the following description:

> But when he put out a hand to push open the gates, he found them chained shut.
>
> “Alohomora!” he said confidently, pointing his wand at the padlock, but nothing happened.
>
> “That won’t work on these,” said Tonks. “Dumbledore bewitched them himself.” Harry looked around.
>
> “I could climb a wall,” he suggested.
>
> “No, you couldn’t,” said Tonks flatly. “Anti-intruder jinxes on all of them. Security’s been tightened a hundredfold this summer.”

When it is actually opened we see that some kind of magic is involved:

> “Well, well, well,” sneered Snape, taking out his wand and tapping the padlock once, so that the chains snaked backward and the gates creaked open.

However, this was apparently an increased level of security after Voldemort returned to the public. In previous years the security was much laxer.